# Historia de huérfanos y fantasmas

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos, usuarios-no-registrados

Hablemos de usuarios no registrados, un tema que es un dolor de cabeza... para todos.

Déjenme contarles un poco lo que veo que pasa. Es bastante largo, pero mi idea al final va ser pedirles sugerencias de cómo creen que se pueda mejorar esto.

Ya sé, los usuarios no registrados aportan muy poco al sitio. Usuarios nuevos, con preguntas que requieren mucho trabajo antes de que puedan recibir una respuesta... ya conocen la historia. Son muy pocos casos, muy poco el contenido valioso, y es demasiado el esfuerzo que hay que hacer para salvarlos de la perdición. Desde el punto de vista de la moderación, hay que dedicarle demasiado tiempo para salvar a muy pocos. Pero no puedo dejar de pensar que esta **es la puerta de ingreso a SOes**. En términos de captación de usuarios, le estamos errando feo. Vamos gente, si queremos que SOes crezca rápido y de forma saludable, tenemos que hacer algo para mejorar nuestra bienvenida. No podemos darnos el mismo lujo de SO de ignorarlos, porque nuestro volumen de usuarios / preguntas / tráfico no es el mismo.

**Credenciales**. En la mayoría de los casos, tienen *casi* las mismas opciones y características de un usuario nuevo que sí se registró, por lo que voy a obviar esta parte y me voy a centrar en el problema: cuando se van, vuelven más tarde y resulta que perdieron sus credenciales de usuario. Las credenciales son simplemente una cookie atada a la PC+navegador con un expire de 6 meses... La verdad es que no sé por qué pasa seguido, pero pasa. Pierden las credenciales y quedan atrapados sin poder hacer nada.

[image: Another brick in the wall]

¿Será porque cambiaron de PC? ¿Usaron otra dirección de mail? ¿O porque estaban en una sesión de incógnito? ¿La política de borrar cookies por la empresa en la que trabajan? ¿O uno de los muchos bugs que tiene SO con los casos de usuarios no registrados? -Ni idea. Sea por lo que sea, nos deja una pregunta que sigue recibiendo comentarios y hasta posibles respuestas, pero el autor no existe más (aunque no lo sepamos).

**Las preguntas huérfanas**, que hacen casi imposible que el usuario siga participando sobre su propia pregunta: no pueden editar, no pueden comentar, no pueden eliminar, no pueden reportar a un mod, intentan sugerir una edición pero se la rechazamos por "*entrar en conflicto con la intención del* ⋘autor⋙", terminan comentando en una respuesta o agregando información de la pregunta en una respuesta, etc.

Y SO tiene sus problemitas también, porque los usuarios pierden sus credenciales más frecuentemente de lo que debería ocurrir. Hay varios bugs dando vuelta. La experiencia del usuario no registrado es realmente mala.
-¡No! Me quedé corto. ¡Es abominablemente fastidiosa!

[image: Bebé triste llorando]

Si después se registran, se mejora el panorama. Esto es más o menos lo que puede pasar:
mando un reporte a un mod, suspira porque no es fácil, piensa "otra vez este!", toma aire, se lo manda a Juan, Juan suspira, casi que ni tiene que ver quién reportó, toma aire, entra en la caja negra de SO, toca unos engranajes, se activa el proceso de merge, vuelve al mod, el mod finalmente puede sacarse de encima ese reporte que estaba ahí hace 1 semana o incluso 1 mes, marcado como útil... el usuario finalmente, si es que sigue en el sitio y no se aburrió de esperar, tiene acceso a su pregunta.

**Las preguntas de fantasmas**. Ahora, si no se registran (y están en todo su derecho de seguir participando así), no hay opción. No hay mucho que se pueda hacer. Yo ni siquiera lo reporto, porque no pueden hacer un merge de 2 usuarios no registrados y alguna vez me rechazaron reportes por este motivo. La pregunta está condenada a seguir sin un autor, sólo queda el fantasma del usuario que alguna vez la hizo.

[image: fantasma]

Normalmente son preguntas que las hizo un usuario nuevo al cual no le dimos ni una chance de editar, por lo que incluso pueden estar algo encaminadas, pero como nadie siquiera responde a los comentarios y se ve que ese usuario (fantasma) no volvió a entrar al sitio, no suelen recibir respuestas. En algunos casos tampoco tienen motivos tan claros para cerrarse, por lo que quedan en un limbo por un año hasta que Comunidad les baile una [roomba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), o indefinidamente si apareció uno de esos +1 que nadie entiende.

**Bueno, que se registren y problema terminado**. Muchos pensarán así, pero esa no es la idea. Más aún, es justamente lo contrario a la política de la red. En SE los usuarios pueden participar sin registrarse. Yo quiero que siga así y no estoy dispuesto a que cambie. Es uno de los pilares en los cuales un sitio crece. Habrá algunos que piensen que, siendo tan fácil, no debería ser un problema, pero el usuario nuevo no sabe cuán fácil es, ni si le llenarán la casilla de mails de publicidad, o cuántos datos privados tendría que compartir antes de poder acceder. La solución tiene que apuntar al problema de los usuarios no registrados para que sigan sin registrarse y puedan interactuar con SOes.

En fin, a los pocos valientes que lleguen a leer hasta acá les pregunto: ¿qué podemos hacer con esta situación? ¿Cómo podemos mejorar a SOes en este aspecto?

Comment: toma tu +1. no tengo idea.. no me hagas pensar un domingo a la noche.. :p

Comment: ah pero llegue hasta el final eh.. lo que no tengo es ni idea que hacer...

Comment: algun comentario del estilo de: hola, sabias que si te registras vas a poder seguir mejor tu pregunta y vas a poder participar del sitio? mira el tour y bla bla bla...

Comment: Creo es muy poco lo que se puede hacer. Como dice @gbianchi, tal vez incluir en el comentario que ponemos para dar la bienvenida algo que indique que es mejor registrarse...

Comment: podemos armar alguna pagina que explique las ventajas de registrarse? tal vez un post en meta? ya se que el sitio permite que no se registren y esta todo bien con eso.. pero... por ahi retenemos alguno que valga la pena

Comment: @gbianchi siéndote sincero, no me va tanto (creo que te imaginabas).. pero es muy probable que esté preguntando algo que no tiene respuesta y si te da ganas, no está nada mal que se discuta. Esa es la idea de esta pregunta!

Comment: ¿Saben si una pregunta de un usuario no registrado pasa por colas de revisión? Sería un buen comienzo ir filtrando aquellas que pueden ser preguntas con múltiples respuestas o votos, las preguntas pobres no son mas que basura y esas de nada nos sirven (suena radical pero "mucho ayuda lo que no estorba"). En resumen creo que el usuario interesado en resolver su problema tendrá la habilidad de hacer caso a recomendaciones y no solo quedarse atrapado en el limbo. Así como el sistema funciona al día de hoy no hay mucho por hacer, si es buena su pregunta ya se salvó, caso contrario, dependerá de él

Comment: @Flxtr respondiendo: sí, cola de primeras preguntas y pueden ir a LQQ si disparan un filtro automático... ¡muy interesante tu opción!. Entiendo que estás hablando de algo que funcione como la cola [Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/5290909) en SO (que no sé si tenemos suficientes revisores, pero sería interesante probar)... Lo que no termino de entender es ¿cómo encajaría con una pregunta huérfana o un usuario fantasma? Si perdieron las credenciales, ¿cómo harían para tener "*la habilidad de hacer caso a recomendaciones*"?

Comment: No conocía el término adecuado, pero sí, sería como el *Triage queue*. Por otro lado, me he encontrado una [pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278612/3200493) de nuestro **Emanuel Ve** (a.k.a. rnd) donde indica un diagrama bastante interesante mostrando un escenario de preguntas insalvables que se adapta al contexto que planteas y tomando como referencia la respuesta de Bradley, sugiere lo mismo que decía @gbianchi, dejar un comentario sería un buen comienzo para aquellos que no saben cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Respondiendo a tener "*la habilidad de hacer caso a recomendaciones*", va relacionado a dejar un comentario al usuario diciendo que si se registra podrá tener diferentes ventajas a dejar únicamente una pregunta y dejarla en el olvido. Para comprobar esto, he realizado una pregunta como invitado, la cual no la veo en las colas (supongo que es por los privilegios) y que en el mail que me llega para completar el registro obtengo un error, primero me [llega la info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22SDh.png), seguí el link, [ups, error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qgdn.png)

Comment: @Flxtr dice que el error es porque ya tenés un usuario con ese mail... es esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140446/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-login-owin-en-c?

Comment: Hasta donde recuerdo no me he registrado con ese mail y nunca lo había usado de este lado, *sigh...*

Comment: Todo lo que me estás contando me suena interesantísimo... estos son los ejemplos que creo que no estamos viendo y que suceden todo el tiempo... Creo que de estas pruebas que estás haciendo sí podemos sacar conclusiones

Comment: Gracias, sin duda alguna sería el *dark side of SOes*. De inicio veo que ya se tiene la propuesta para echar la cola de triaje y que no solo ayudaría al escenario planteado en esta pregunta, también a preguntas por usuarios registrados que constantemente estamos guiando como si fueran niños chiquitos.