# Instauremos una cola de revisión "triaje" para que solo las preguntas con cierto nivel entren en la página de inicio

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas, colas-de-revisión

En [Workflow changes for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552/209901) se comenta el 1 de junio de 2021:

> - The Triage queue will also be available on all sites but only turned on by default on Stack Overflow. Have a meta discussion and ask a moderator to [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) if your site wishes to add the Triage queue.

Es decir, que se pueda pedir que se incluya.

---

<sub>Leyendo [Montones de preguntas de muy baja calidad (y respuestas igualmente malas)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3192/83) me vinieron muchas ideas y empecé a escribir una respesta. Como se estaba desviando rápidamente hacia una propuesta, la pongo como pregunta y así podrá generar mayor y mejor debate.</sub>

A los usuarios regulares le molestan las preguntas de muy baja calidad, pues denotan que nos estamos topando con un vampiro en busca de ayuda y que huirá con su solución bajo el brazo.

Se habla con frecuencia del concepto [Septiembre eterno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septiembre_Eterno) para designar un flujo constante de nuevos usuarios que no conocen las reglas de un sitio y degradan la comunidad en la que aterrizan. Corriges a uno, lo educas, pero ya te han salido cinco más. Te armas de paciencia, sigues intentando *formar* al nuevo usuario, y llegan más y más. Un problema de difícil solución con el que se enfrenta toda la red Stack Exchange (y especialmente Stack Overflow) desde el principio de sus tiempos.

Sin embargo, creo que el problema más grande no es que la gente pregunte cosas malas, sino que la gente con ganas de contestar se encuentre cada vez con más preguntas malas. Nos podemos permitir perder usuarios *vampiros*, pero **mucho más grave es perder usuarios con conocimientos y ganas de responder**.

Por ello, es especialmente dañino que la página de inicio la copen preguntas con bajo nivel, con malos formatos y títulos poco indicativos. Preguntas que necesitan cocerse un rato antes de entrar por la puerta grande del sitio y recibir respuestas.

Esencialmente, **necesitamos que las preguntas dispuestas para contestar estén ya lo suficientemente trabajadas para que los que las lean puedan pasar a responderlas**.

Por ello, creo que es bueno tomar en consideración lo que comentó Shog9 (CM de Stack Exchange) hace casi cuatro años en [Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/209901) e **implementar una cola de triaje** que sirva para hacer esa cocción a las preguntas para que lleguen a la página de inicio con las clarificaciones ya hechas.

Lo que propongo ya existe, se llama Triage y [Stack Overflow la tiene](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats), con una [guía de uso muy extensa y detallada](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/1983854).

Básicamente lo que **mide es la calidad de las preguntas** de la siguiente manera:

Alguien pregunta. Su pregunta no entra directamente en la página de inicio, sino que se aparta en base a ciertas variables. En ese *aparte* se permite a los usuarios de confianza que la miren con calma, y:

- Si la pregunta se considera buena, entra en la página de inicio.
- Si la pregunta es mejorable:

  - si lo que falla es el formato o algo así, los usuarios la modifican.
  - si lo que falla es algo que solo el autor saber, se lo indica y se espera que la edita.
- Si la pregunta es un trunio, se manda a la basura de la historia.

<sub>Hablo de memoria, no encuentro la referencia de que las preguntas no estén en la página de inicio durante este proceso. Pero creo que es así. Lo contrario no sería lógico</sub>

¿Qué os parece?

Comment: Esto me recuerda al proyecto que se propuso de "sistema de tutelaje" pero aplicado a una cola. La idea de que no aparezcan las publicaciones directamente en el sitio si no en una seccion de revisión es la misma pero incluyendo a todos los posibles revisores y no solo los voluntarios *tutores*. A mi me parece genial algo asi ya que muchas de baja calidad no se cierran lo suficientemente rapido e incluso se llegan  a contestar y aceptar sin siquiera tener la calidad minima.

Comment: Mi apoyo total. Necesitamos esa cola ya.

Comment: @lois6b ¿te refieres a la idea de [Mentoría](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/496/83) que Juan M incluyó en sus [objetivos de 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/83)? Lo bueno es que esta ya está implementada, solamente sería pedir que se incluyera en este sitio.

Comment: @fedorqui estaba buscando publicacion de Meta pero creo que solo se habló por el chat ([aqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33408788#33408788) empieza la charla en el chat) . Esa que enlazas es más enfocada a los webcast. Habia una con la idea de hacerlo dentro del sitio. A ver si encuentro referncias heheh

Comment: Encontré esto: [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/1595451). Sólo le dí una vista rápida, ahí se incluye un diagrama de flujo en el que se indica que con base en una puntuación la pregunta puede o no mostrarse en la página de inicio, se invita a probar y tiene montones de comentarios, no logré identificar si la prueba ya se dió por terminada. En cuanto al hilo en Meta SE es un "feature-request" que no tiene etiqueta de estado.

Comment: @Rubén ¡buen descubrimiento! _Triage_ en SO actualmente está íntimamente relacionada con _Help and Improvement_. Debo bucear para ver cuándo se creó cada una, pues creo que la 2.ª salió un tiempo después. En cuanto a la prueba, no sé en qué punto quedó, pero de todos modos sigue usándose por lo que entiendo que se dio por satisfactoria.

Comment: @fedorqui justo estaba escribiendo lo mismo... H&I vino mucho después... fue un cambio posterior que me imagino que se puede implementar sin esa ruta perfectamente... por cierto, hace muy poco había comentado lo mismo con Flxter en [Historia de huérfanos y fantasmas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3177/historia-de-hu%c3%a9rfanos-y-fantasmas#comment11292_3177)

Comment: Triage!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! y usemos el mismo umbral de rep que alla.. y listo.. a ver si se ponen las pilas...

Comment: Creo que ahora seria una buena idea para probar esto...

Comment: @gbianchi, pq ahora es el momento ideal, que cambió?

Comment: @Japv porque hay muchisimas preguntas de usuarios nuevos de bajisima calidad. De esa forma se evita que lleguen hasta que esten bien hechas. Y se ahorra trabajo de cierre y limpieza para aquellos usuarios que no van a seguir con su pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi, pero entonces habría que revisar más cosas, como se haría, 3 votos para que se acepte la publicación?, y además cuanto tiempo debe esperar el AP, para ver su publicación, si actualmente hay preguntas que se demoran muchísimo pa ser cerradas, como vas a garantizar que no pase esto con la nueva cola triage

Comment: @gbianchi, corres el riesgo de que buenas preguntas se demoren en ser publicadas, ya que esa revisión recae sobre la comunidad , no es automática, como vas a garantizar que una buena pregunta no se demore horas, días etc en ser publicada

Comment: Si esto se puede apagar y prender a provecho, tenemos dos opciones. Volver a replicar las metricas que hizo mariano en su momento (Mariano volve!!!!) o probar como estamos haciendo con los 3 votos y ver que pasa. Todo tiene su pro y su contra. Pero cuantas preguntas de nuevos (y enfatizo, nuevos) usuarios son buenas, contra cuantas necesitamos que las retoquen varias veces o que directamente las borren?

Answer (score 7):

¡Es una excelente idea! ¡Me encanta! ¡¡¡Quiero que esté funcionando YA!!!

Pero estoy convencido de que aún **no** es momento.

---

Para empezar a explicar por qué no es momento, quiero mostrarles la Cola de [Primeras Publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/), una que también se accede con 500, pero que sólo necesita 1 único revisor para completarse. Estas son las métricas:     <sup><sub>(*también las publiqué [acá](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2145/127))</sub></sup>

[image: Captura al 19/2/18. Cantidad de revisiones y demora (media diaria) de la cola de Primeras Publicaciones, agrupadas por semana, para los últimos 12 meses.]

- Ahí puse que muestre cantidad de revisiones (amarillo) y demora (celeste).
- Miren cómo la demora media en minutos (celeste) viene estando **por arriba de 1 hora** desde que se publica hasta que se revisa! Eso es lo que se tarda para una cola que debería ser instantánea (y es la media, algunas revisiones tardan muchísimo más).

Miren el historial de esta cola (abrir en otra pestaña):   <sup>(tapé los nombres)</sup>

[image: 29 de 50 (58%) No se requiere ninguna acción]

- Son sólo un puñado de usuarios (siempre los mismos), y muy espaciados en el tiempo... hay pausas muy largas entre uno y otro. Pausas que dejan publicaciones sin revisar por mucho tiempo.
- Estoy mostrando la captura en una hora pico, ni les cuento a la noche/madrugada!
- Y ¿vieron la acción elegida? Es un *No se requiere ninguna acción* tras otro (marqué con las cruces)... Yo no recuerdo cuándo fue la última vez que seleccioné eso, pero está muy mal.
- Ya lo decíamos [hace un año y medio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/861/127), y creo que se ha empeorado. Es un problema enorme que se esté revisando así (pero no quiero irme de tema, esto quedará para alguna otra publicación).

Primeras Publicaciones es la cola con menos requisitos, la más sencilla y rápida, y aún estamos fallando en esto.

**Mi punto:** Está genial la iniciativa de implementar Triage, me encanta... Pero no estamos preparados lamentablemente. Nos faltan muchos pasos hasta llegar a eso. No conseguiríamos 3 usuarios en una revisión rápida jamás. Ojalá no fuese así, pero es la realidad. Las revisiones actuales no resisten ningún análisis.
Y al mismo tiempo creo que es una discusión genial, que se tiene que dar en el sitio.

Triage es una cola que se diseñó para algo completamente diferente: limpiar la página porque había tantas malas preguntas que no se podía ver ninguna de las buenas. Estamos hablando de un volumen exhorbitante de publicaciones, sumado a que se había priorizado cómo se muestran las preguntas, para que muestre más las que no estaban respondidas: un cambio con buenas intenciones pero con un resultado desastroso. Se puede leer el origen del problema en [*The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/5290909) y ver las diferencias con nuestra situación actual.

Lo que estaríamos haciendo con un Triage es demorar las respuestas a una pregunta aceptable. O también, estaríamos dirigiendo las publicaciones de baja calidad para que la mayoría terminen evaluadas por un moderador, cosa que ya sucede ahora y no aportaría diferencias.

Y también es paciencia. El número de usuarios va subiendo, y es lógico que aparezcan camadas nuevas que no saben cómo funciona la cosa y cómo moderar, en especial en épocas de éxamenes en cada uno de los países.

Buscando información sobre la implementación de Triage en otro sitios, encontré esta publicación que les recomiendo leer: [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251737/304899) (no la traduzco porque es larga y realmente vale la pena leerla), pero se menciona que ni siquiera está del todo ajustada para que funcione bien en SO, y que podría llegar a pensarse implementar en alguno de los sitios más grandes, no en otros.

**¿Qué propondría?** Dejar esto dentro de un plan más largo, de acá a 1-2 años en principio, con objetivos intermedios, yendo paso a paso.

Por ejemplo (tomen esto sólo como un borrador):

1. **Documentar** mejor en Meta lo que hay que hacer en cada cola. Por ejemplo, que quede claro que no pueden poner "*no se requiere ninguna acción*" (salvo casos muy raros), que hay que revisar bien, editar editar editar editar, pedir aclaraciones, votar y OMITIR. Y lo mismo para todas las colas.
2. **Comprometer** a los revisores más experimentados en que revisen a los revisores, y les pasen links a toda la documentación de Meta que les explica qué significa cada botón de la revisión y qué se espera que hagan. Estar mucho más afinados, con una masa importante de revisores que saben lo que hacen.

   Es cierto que está el tema de que subieron los privilegios con la graduación. Y también es lógico que haya un poco de cansancio en algunos (me incluyo). Después de estar focalizados en "*tenemos que graduarnos, tenemos que graduarnos, tenemos que graduarnos*", nos graduamos!!! Y a muchos se nos va un poco el aire y la fuerza con la que veníamos... Lleva tiempo hasta que volvemos a poner foco. Pero aún así, sigue habiendo muy pocos revisando en comparación a los que pueden revisar.
3. **Audits** - Que son MUY problemáticas para implementar. ¿Saben que al principio sólo empeoran las colas, no? Ahora, yo no me animo a implementar audits sin que antes estén más en sintonía los revisores (y el resto de la comunidad) con el equipo de moderadores y CM.

   Los casos que tiran los audits pueden ser realmente malos y donde tomar una acción diferente a la que espera el sistema es realmente lo que se debe hacer... Entonces empiezan a aparecer preguntas en Meta de "*por qué no aprobé esto*"; y tienen razón, entonces empezamos a pedir que se elimine un cierto audit de la cola. Y sabemos que esa respuesta puede no ser rápida, entonces pasó 1 mes y ese audit malo está ahí.

   Por eso tienen que estar muy ajustados los primeros 2 puntos antes de ir con audits.
4. **Afianzar** la cantidad de revisores constantes, promoviendo que la gente revise seguido, y que haya más involucrados... una masa crítica.

... y recién ahí

5. **Evaluar** métricas, ver cuáles son los problemas que estamos teniendo... Si sigue siendo un tema de baja calidad y vemos que está inundando la página, ahí sí podemos pensar en implementar un nueva cola, ya sea *Help & Improvement* o *Triage*.

No antes de haber dominado la cola más sencilla de todas (Primeras Publicaciones).

En fin, no quiero matar la inercia de tu propuesta, pero creo que es importante ver esto.

---

**Referencias**. Estos son algunos de los links que repasé antes de publicar:

- Audits:

  - [Teste da fila de análise:](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4993/53463)
  - [Precisamos de auditoria para a ferramenta de auditoria?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5343/53463)
- Help & Improvement

  - [Is the “Help and Improvement” queue just bad-question purgatory?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291741/5290909)
  - [Help and Improvement review queue not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291562/5290909)
- Triage:

  - [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251737/304899)
  - [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions (and a proposed solution)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/5290909)
  - [Triage “Requires Editing” Notification to New Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363221/5290909)

Comment: el problema sigue siendo.. si los que tiene rep contestan cualquier cosa.. y si nadie le pone a un primer usuario que lea el tour.. entonces estamos en la misma que nada.. veo ediciones de titulos y cosas superfluos.. y nadie si quiera los mando a leer el tour.. y yo no tengo forma de decirle al usuario X, que tiene que hacer de tal o cual forma. Con lo cual es dificil enseñarle a los que estan revisando como revisar. No se.. ademas como si fuera poco el otro dia nos dimos cuenta de que los que se postularon para moderador.. no quedo ninguno moderando :( (bah, con excepciones)

Comment: @gbianchi si tuviese una respuesta para eso, hubiese publicado en [tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3192/127). Simplemente estoy seguro de que no podemos implementar Triage en SOes por el momento, de que no es por acá la cosa... Y creo que sí podés comentarle a un revisor sobre una acción en la que no coincidís, nada te lo impide, especialmente si te encontrás con una pregunta que debería haber tenido otro tratamiento, revisás el timeline, ves qué revisiones tuvo, y en qué se falló. Por ejemplo, si una pregunta de muy baja calidad se cerrara rápido, no nos importaría el resto.

Comment: Sabes q en mi lista de criticas estas en las ultimas posiciones.. junto con varios otros. Hoy implemente otro metodo en las colar. Reporte algunos comentarios medio agresivos y siempre destaque lo de leer el tour. Inclusive en respuestas a preguntas dudosas. Igual se me acaban las ideas.

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente que dedicaras el tiempo (¡y gran sapiencia!) a responder a esta propuesta, después de comentármela primero por chat. Comparto buena parte de los argumentos y dan ganas de coger la hoja de ruta y luchar para que se implemente paso a paso. Sin embargo, me surge una duda: si ahora no estamos listos para Triage, ¿por qué íbamos a estarlo más en un año? ¿estamos compensando el aumento de número de preguntas con el aumento en el número de revisores (aparte de por el hecho de que la gente va cogiendo reputación y, por ende, privilegios)?

Comment: @fedorqui estuve pensando bastante cómo es que en el futuro podríamos reconocer si estamos listos para implementar H&I o Triage, y no tengo la respuesta. Sin embargo, creo que como **mínimo** deberíamos tener una cierta actividad de revisores que garanticen 3 revisiones en poco tiempo, y que nuestros problemas empiecen a ser que la cantidad de preguntas en el home tape a las buenas preguntas... No sé si será 1-2 años o más (usé esa medida para hablar de un tiempo futuro sin proyectar nada)... Llegado ese momento, podríamos preguntarle a algún CM de SO que realmente tenga experiencia en esto.

Comment: @fedorqui creo que la evolución de un sitio no es algo lineal, sino más bien errático pero por etapas (etapas que tienen mcuhas similitudes entre diferentes sitios de SE y su evolución -comparemos!)... Preguntaste si estamos compensando el aumento en preguntas con el número de revisores, y creo que es mejor analizarlo cualitativamente: al menos desde mi impresión personal, se bajó bastante en la calidad de revisiones... pero son ciclos, y esto suele ir acompañado de publicaciones en Meta y acciones de moderadores para ir corrigiéndose (-¿será momento de ir pensando en un 4to moderador?).

Comment: [¡En SOpt tienen audits!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4238/28073)

Answer (score 4):

El problema principal sería que aquí hay muchos menos usuarios con reputación alta que en SO_en, por lo que existe el riesgo de que la cola de triaje se convierta en un obstáculo para gente nueva que entra con buenas preguntas pero que no son revisadas...

Comment: Es un buen punto el que expones, pero debes tener algo en cuenta. En [so], la reputación necesaria para acceder a esta cola es de solo 500. Creo que habrá ya muchos usuarios con esa reputación aqui (seguro que alguien sabe como buscar cuantos exactamente) por lo que no creo que sea un obstáculo

Comment: Este es un punto importante, claro está. Sin embargo, entiendo que sería cuestión de definir un umbral algo más bajo para que más gente opte a revisar en esta cola. Al fin y al cabo, si alguien pregunta y quiere que su pregunta esté presente en el sitio __ya__, seguramente es mejorj dejarlo pasar. Que deba esperar 10-15 minutos (o incluso más) no es mala noticia.

Comment: @Pikoh [hay 388](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/alltime/es-stackoverflow/2015-12-01/) con más de 500 de rep. (mira la tabla de la derecha y abajo)

Comment: @lois6b efectivamente, no lo encontraba ;) 388 parecen bastantes, asi que la cuestion no es el número de revisores, sino si realmente se revisarian o no :)

Comment: @Pikoh también sería tomar en cuenta que los 388 usuarios no son activos en las colas de revisión, lo cual disminuye ese número. Aún así, es un buen punto y es preferible tener pocos usuarios (supongamos que menos de 100) ya que estaríamos asegurando que los pocos o muchos involucrados en las revisiones se tomarían en serio el trabajo de revisores.