# ¿Primeras publicaciones, tardías?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión, revisiones

Hace algunos días que he estado revisando la cola de **Primeras publicaciones**, me he fijado que entre las 03:00 UTC y las 3:30 UTC han llegado una cantidad de preguntas que oscila entre 3-8 en donde la fecha de su formulación ha sido tardía.

Normalmente esta cola de revisión avisa de las primeras publicaciones de los usuarios a los pocos minutos de su formulación, pero en este caso me ha mostrado preguntas de hace varios días en que se formularon, algunas hasta con respuestas aceptadas.

Aquí pongo un ejemplo de hoy:

[image: Primera publicación tardía]

Aquí mi historial de revisiones:

[image: Historial de reviciones]

Un ejemplo de una primera publicación con respuesta aceptada, según el historial anterior:

[Pasar parametro de una Actividad a una Clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141470/pasar-parametro-de-una-actividad-a-una-clase)

Me he dado a la tarea de investigar y en la mayoría de los casos los usuarios que formulan la pregunta no se encuentran registrados.

#### ¿Posible bug en la cola de revisión?

#### ¿Aplicará solo a esta cola?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasó fue que:

1. El usuario hizo su primera pregunta A

   - Esta fue evaluada en la cola de Primeras Publicaciones
2. Hizo una segunda pregunta B (y quizás más preguntas también).

   - Esta es por la que estás preguntando: [Pasar parametro de una Actividad a una Clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141470/127).
3. Varios días después, se eliminó la pregunta A

   - [Error simulador de Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141102/127) (sólo se ve con 10k) - **Eliminada hace 1 hora** por Comunidad por ser una pregunta con una puntuación de cero o negativa, sin respuestas con puntaje positivo ni aceptadas o con votos de reapertura pendientes, que estuvieron cerradas por 9 o más días, y que no han sido editadas en los últimos 9 días ([descrito en el faq](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127)).

     - Y esta había sido la revisión de esa primera pregunta: [/review/first-posts/84871](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/84871)
       (acá se ve la revisión, se vea o no la pregunta eliminada).
4. El sistema detectó que la pregunta B es ahora la **primera** pregunta de ese usuario, y que no pasó por la cola de Primeras Publicaciones.

   - La envió a la cola y la analizaste!
     <sub>* Aunque creo que se pueden encontrar algunas cosas para corregir, [no está bueno que elijas "*No se requiere ninguna acción*"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/127), sería recomendable evitar este botón a toda costa. Casi siempre hay algo para comentar/editar en primeras publicaciones, y si es una buena pregunta, por favor votala +1!.</sub>

Este tipo de comportamiento puede enviar una pregunta *vieja* como "primera", tanto a la Cola de Primeras Publicaciones, como a Respuestas Tardías (aunque es muchísimo más raro que se de este segundo caso).

Lo ves a las 3:00 UTC porque hay poca actividad en el sitio y es más evidente, pero el proceso de eliminación automática sucede constantemente, cada 1 hora si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: Tremenda investigación, muy bien perseguido.