# Votamos poco ... ¡ y respondemos mucho?

Tags: discusión

Estamos de acuerdo en que en el sitio se vota poco ... pero es que, además, creo que respondemos **demasiado**. Vamos, que últimamente **no me da tiempo a poner un comentario** para que el OP mejore su pregunta, adecuándola al sitio: ejemplo mínimo y verificable, mensajes de error, líneas que producen los susodichos mensajes ... en fín, **hacer que la pregunta sea útil para otros**. Antes de comentar, ya aparecen 1 o 2 respuestas :-O ¡ Pardiez !

Tenía entendido que este era uno de los objetivos del sitio: construir una base de datos con preguntas y respuestas sobre programación **de utilidad para todos**. Pero parece que no, que el objetivo es responder rápido. Más rápido. ¡ Soy el más rápido de todos !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto lo puedo entender de usuario nuevos ... ¡ Pero es que hay usuarios con cierta antigüedad y una reputación **bastante respetable** que profesan el mismo comportamiento !

Bajo mi punto de vista, una pregunta mal redactada/incompleta/confusa pierde su utilidad, mas allá de para el OP. Hace difícil buscarla, lo que conlleva perder visitas y duplicar preguntas/respuestas.

Yo, sin ir mas lejos, ante errores, suelo buscar **por el mensaje de error exacto** que estoy obteniendo. Y con preguntas incompletas, pues como que esta táctica no sirve. Igual el mensaje ni aparece en la descripción del problema.

Compañeros ...

¿ Podríamos tener menos prisa en responder e intentar que las preguntas **sean de ayuda para futuros usuarios** ?

Comment: El [problema del pistolero más rápido del Oeste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: De los rapidos tenemos varios.. pero desgraciadamente no pasan por aca :(

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, se que hay muchos usuarios que responden antes de leer la pregunta, y entre esos algunos que justamente no tienen costumbre de votar las publicaciones de otros usuarios, pero toda participación en la pagina es voluntaria, es complicado exigir que los usuarios sigan un alguna conducta mas allá de lo que estipulan las reglas.

Comment: @the-breaker Lo se ... lo único que puedo hacer es justamente esto, exponer mi opinión/queja en *meta*, en un intento de hacérselo saber a los nuevos y refrescar la memoria de los veteranos.

Comment: ¿Qué se te ocurre que se podría hacer para evitar estas respuestas *prematuras*?

Comment: @fedorqui La verdad es que nada. Si estuviera limitado a usuarios noveles ... se podrían usar los puntos o alguna estadística sobre sus respuestas. Pero los usuarios veteranos *chafan* ese plan. Siempre podemos votar negativo, pero no termino de verlo como una solución. Así que aquí estoy, en *meta*, *pataleando* mi *rabieta*. ¿ Tal vez alguna publicación en *meta* sobre el **autocontrol** ?

Comment: @Trauma, comparto tu preocupación, incluso si esporadicamente haya sido yo mismo, "el más rápido del oeste" ;-), pero en mi opinión, no nos debería preocupar tanto la velocidad de una respuesta ya sea, la de un usuario novel, como la de un histórico. Incluso, tampoco deberíamos preocuparnos si la respuesta en sí, es de calidad o no. El verdadero "quid" de la cuestión es por qué preguntas que no cumplen un mínimo de calidad siguen "vivitas y coleando" en el sistema. Volvemos a lo que muchas veces hemos discutido, las colas de revisión.

Comment: También, hay una resistencia de muchos usuarios a agregar la información que se les pide, a mejorar sus propias preguntas, con suerte algunas cosas se pueden deducir de los comentarios, no olvidemos que tenemos la posibilidad de mejorar una pregunta agregando y/o modificando lo que hiciera falta, si vamos a responder una pregunta que no está del todo bien, mejoremosla. Si hacer esto es "vandalizar" demasiado la pregunta, hagamos una nueva pregunta y respondamosla e indiquemos la original como la duplicada de la nueva.

Comment: Siento tu dedo acusador apuntándome.

Comment: @fedorqui considero que lo que se puede hacer de momento cuando un usuario responde rápido y ademas brinda una respuesta que no responde directamente la pregunta o es de baja calidad es votarle negativo e indicarle que pase por este post.

Comment: @the-breaker pero eso lo normal, el problema es con las respuestas que sí responden a la pregunta y son de buena calidad o al menos de calidad aceptable porque tampoco se trata de castigar a las respuestas basándonos en la pregunta.

Comment: @blonfu es cierto, si la respuesta es correcta no hace falta tomar ninguna medida, solo mencione el caso de si la respuesta es prematura y no brinda mucha información.

Comment: @blonfu ¿ Puede una pregunta incompleta tener una buena respuesta ? Entiendo que puede tener una respuesta **que le sirva al OP**, pero ¿ Es eso suficiente para considerarla una buena respuesta ? Me remito a los últimos párrafos de esta pregunta. Si el OP no indica siquiera el mensaje de error, y en la respuesta no se indica ... ¿ Que acción tomar ?

Answer (score 11):

> Bajo mi punto de vista, una pregunta mal redactada/incompleta/confusa pierde su utilidad, mas allá de para el OP. Hace difícil buscarla, lo que conlleva perder visitas y duplicar preguntas/respuestas.
>
> — Trauma —

> ¿Qué se te ocurre que se podría hacer para evitar estas respuestas *prematuras*?
>
> — fedorqui —

La clave está en detectar las **preguntas malas™** y las **respuestas prematuras<sup>©</sup>**.

#### ¿Cómo definimos una pregunta mala™?

La pregunta mala™ se distingue por:

- Tiene algún tipo de reporte sin resolver.
- Carece de código (*ejemplo mínimo y verificable*).
- Es corta (no explica cuáles son los *mensajes de error* ni las *líneas que producen esos mensajes*).

#### ¿Cómo definimos una respuesta prematura<sup>©</sup>?

Una respuesta prematura sería toda aquella respuesta que se haga sobre una pregunta mala™.

---

### Posibles soluciones.

#### Fuerza bruta.

Una posible solución sería prohibir las respuestas prematuras<sup>©</sup>: que el apartado de respuesta no esté habilitado si la pregunta cumple con las características de pregunta mala™.

Esta solución es inviable, ya que si una pregunta carece de código no tiene por qué ser a priori mala™, tampoco tiene por qué serlo una pregunta corta… pero tal vez sí que podría ser viable inhabilitar las respuestas (o poner una alarma) en aquellas preguntas que tengan reportes pendientes de resolver el problema surge entonces cuando quien responde es más rápido que los reportes.

Esta solución no me gusta, carga de molestias a quien responde por un problema que ni siquiera generó: el problema es de la pregunta por ser mala™. Por eso prefiero…

#### [Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)).

El proceso de pregunta podría afinarse más para reducir al máximo las preguntas malas™ si se desarrollase un *Wizard* que guiase al usuario en el proceso. Algo pantalla a pantalla como…

- ¿Qué tipo de pregunta quieres hacer?

  1. Tengo un fallo en mi código.

     - Describe el fallo.
     - Pega aquí el **texto** de tu código.
     - Indica el error que estás recibiendo.
     - Indica cuáles son tus datos de entrada.
     - Indica cuáles son los datos de salida que esperas.
  2. Tengo una duda sobre un código.

     - Explica tu duda.
     - Pega aquí el **texto** del código.
  3. No se cómo funciona una característica.

     - Describe la característica.
     - Explica tu duda.
  4. …

Tras pasar por todas las pantallas del *Wizard*, se podría editar la pregunta en modo texto.

---

™ Mal redactada/incompleta/confusa.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Deberíamos exigir el Wizard ya. Complementariamente, la cola de revisión Triage podría ayudar, pues las preguntas potencialmente flojas pasan primero por allí y no salen hasta que están listas. Debatimos al respecto hace año y medio en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/83

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con el wizard, ¿porqué no podemos usarlo en SOes cuando el sitio en inglés [ya implementa una sección guiada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KOH9.png) desde hace un tiempo? Creo que se debería exigir esta ventana para las preguntas de los nuevos usuarios o con x nivel de reputación.

Comment: @JheymanMejia no tenía ni idea de la existencia de el Wizard en la versión inglesa de la web. Pinta bastante bien.

Comment: @fedorqui Lo del *wizard*, como ya dije en su día, lo necesitamos **ya**. Pero ¿ una cola que **retenga** las preguntas ? ¿ No *espantará* eso a muchos nuevos usuarios ?

Comment: @Trauma bueno todo tiene sus pros y sus contras : )

Comment: La idea del wizzard parece ideal siempre y cuando no sea restrictivo, como ya comentaron hay preguntas correctas que no requieren de código o mensajes de error.

Comment: @solamente el sitio en español tiene ese molesto "error" desde hace un tiempo, te obliga es escribir un texto extenso si adjuntas primero un pequeño código, también pasa con las imágenes.