# ¿Cómo gestionar las preguntas que son ejercicios de clase?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, usuarios-nuevos, advertencias-en-preguntas, trabajo-escolar

Llega octubre y en España comienza el año lectivo: colegios, institutos, universidades vuelven a su actividad tras el verano...

Y, como cada año, nos inundan con preguntas donde [sólo tenemos el enunciado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298086/escriba-una-funci%C3%B3n-en-python-para-leer-tres-n%C3%BAmeros-a-b-c-y-verifique-cu%C3%A1nt) y [ni un tímido intento del OP por resolverlas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298172/estructuras-de-selecci%C3%B3n). Muchas son las ya clásicas [*Calcular el N-ésimo elemento de la serie de Fibonacci de manera recursiva*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297274/c-sucesi%C3%B3n-fibonacci-funci%C3%B3n-recursiva),  [*Invertir una cadena de caracteres*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55905/c%C3%B3mo-revierto-los-valores-de-una-cadena-de-caracteres-en-c), etc.

¿Cómo deberíamos tratar estas preguntas?

Parece que lo añadir *recomendaciones* según las etiquetas o la reputación/antigüedad del usuario ya no se está manteniendo, pero añadir a los usuarios en sus primeras preguntas algo como **No os hacemos las tareas de clase** es algo que se me ha pasado por la cabeza [más de una vez](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51954060#51954060).

Comment: Yo sigo firme en la idea de añadir una [sección guiada para las preguntas de usuarios nuevos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4321/votamos-poco-y-respondemos-mucho/4324#comment17903_4324) en SOes tal cual lo hace el sitio en inglés. No sé porqué no se ha implementado esto aún o si se tienen planes siquiera para hacerlo.

Comment: pregunta relacionada [Preguntas de “¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/77879)

Comment: pero que tal si hacemos un [regex con tarea o ejercicios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/28035)?

Comment: @JackNavaRow suena bien, ¡adelante! Deberá ser una nueva pregunta con [meta-tag:característica-nueva].

Comment: legendario @fedorqui no sabria ni como preguntar

Comment: @JackNavaRow yo hice una petición en [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83), por si te vale como ejemplo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si bien el [*septiembre eterno*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septiembre_Eterno) parece un mal común, en octubre se intensifica :)

Creo que debemos gestionar las cosas como con cualquier otra pregunta:

- Intentando clarificar el enunciado
- Animando a los usuarios a mostrar qué han intentado
- Conteniendo a la gente para que no responda hasta que la pregunta no sea válida
- Reportando las preguntas que se borran tras obtener respuesta (deben ser recuperadas)
- Animando al usuario a que se prodigue en el sitio: ¡es una gran ocasión para obtener nuevos usuarios!
- Votando por contenido solamente: si un usuario nuevo tiene -3, no le votemos positivamente por pena. Simplemente dejemos de votar negativo, por ejemplo.
- Buscando duplicados y mejorando preguntas potencialmente canónicas para evitar estar explicando las mismas cosas una y otra vez.
- Editando las preguntas para que se lean y encuentren más fácilmente.
- Etiquetando las preguntas para que estén mejor clasificadas.

Comment: Lo de dejar de votar negativo me parece importante, el efecto avalancha en las redes sociales y similares puede transformar un leve reproche en una desaprobación generalizada.

Comment: Exacto, hay que tener en cuenta qué objetivos comunes tenemos. ¿Queremos mejorar el conocimiento? Sí. ¿Queremos ridiculizar a la gente? No. ¿Queremos definir unos estándares de calidad? Sí. ¿Queremos que la gente vuelva? También.

Comment: E intentar ayudar al ignorante, ya que no informar (Siempre y cuando este se esfuerze por entender) al ignorante es como quemar un auto estropeado.

Comment: Relacionado con este tema ¿Que se hace con un usuario que tras ver que claramente es una tarea le da la solución en respuestas? ¿Se ignora sin mas, se vota en negativo (Aunque este correcta la pregunta)?

Comment: @ICodeForCaffeine depende del caso. Si la respuesta es buena, votarla negativa es hacer un flaco favor. Dicho lo cual, nunca está de más comentar al autor de la respuesta que siempre es mejor esperar a tener una buena pregunta, bien formulada.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón, siempre me rondaba la duda de que hacer en esas ocasiones que no son pocas, así que me ceñiré a comentar lo que me has indicado cuando vuelva a ver dicha situación, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que en esos caso, lo mejor es no contestar exactamente lo que preguntan, sino guiarlos de manera correcta para que ellos mismos puedan obtener la respuesta, me explico con un ejemplo.

Si preguntan como calcular la división de 20 en MySQL, pues les explicas como se divide cualquier numero en MySQL, para que cuando menos se tomen el tiempo de entender la sintaxis  y utilizar lo aprendido.

Comment: enseñar a pescar en vez de darle el pescado, siempre como un comentario mas que respuesta creo que sirve este tipo de "ayudas", quizas luego de darle esa informacion puede tener mas conocimientos y mejorar su pregunta o hasta resolver su problema

Comment: A eso me refería, aunque creo que mi respuesta no fue muy bien recibida, ya tengo 2 negativos.

Comment: El problema es que debemos motivarles a hacer buenas preguntas, a que editen la ya existente... o acabaremos con una muy mala pregunta y una respuesta que es una guía general que no responde realmente. Antes prefiero limpiar borrando la pregunta