# ¿Se podría crear una pregunta/respuesta de referencia para cerrar la pregunta con más facilidad en ciertos casos?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-canónica

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Hay casos en los que la pregunta no se adapta de una forma clarísima al formato del sitio. Por ejemplo, el OP pide que le resuelvan un ejercicio, o pregunta por dónde debe empezar para aprender un lenguaje `X`... A veces usuarios que conocen poco el sitio intentan responder a esa pregunta, llenando el sitio de contenido que no aporta nada.

Si un usuario más avanzado con medalla de oro en alguna de las etiquetas de la pregunta la ve, podría cerrarla en ese mismo instante marcándola como duplicada de otra, sin tener que esperar a que otros la marquen para cierre (en ese intervalo es donde muchos usuarios desprevenidos responden). Pero esto no es posible porque no existe una pregunta/respuesta a la cual referir.

¿Piensan que sería una buena idea tener para cada uno de estos casos que se repiten muy a menudo una pregunta/respuesta de referencia para agilizar el cierre y mantener el sitio más limpio? ¿De qué forma se podría implementar esto? Yo pienso en algo global, que sirva para todas las etiquetas, luego, según la pregunta y las etiquetas de ésta, un usuario con medalla de oro la cerraría refiriendo a esa única pregunta/respuesta.

¿O piensan que es una idea descabellada?

Un ejemplo de lo que digo es esta pregunta/respuesta: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977/29967). La misma se usa mucho para cerrar preguntas basadas en NPE de Java.

En el caso que expongo, la pregunta/respuesta de referencia serían quizá wiki de coumunidad, para evitar la tentación de beneficiarse de los puntos y podría ser fruto de un consenso discutido aquí.

Comment: Definitivamente si. Yo estoy totalmente a favor de crear preguntas/respuestas canónicas para temas que reciben un alto número de preguntas, y poder cerrar las mismas como duplicadas.

Comment: Mi anterior comentario se refiere a respuestas canónicas, que es lo que yo he entendido. Pero leyendo la respuesta de @PabloLozano tal vez te refieras a una pregunta/respuesta sin contenido más alla de _no hacemos tareas_. Podrías aclararlo?

Comment: @Pikoh no se trata de algo como lo que dice Pablo en ningún caso. Yo aspiraría a algo de más calidad, pero sin tener claro cómo podría implementarse, en caso de que fuese factible. Por eso plantee la pregunta, quizá podamos llegar a un consenso sobre: 1. Si es factible hacerlo; 2. De qué forma podría hacerse

Comment: Perfecto, entonces es mas o menos lo que yo había entendido. Gracias por aclararlo :)

Comment: Yo no entiendo muy bien la pregunta tampoco... ¿Quieres hacer una pregunta/respuesta general para los casos de gente que viene a preguntar sobre ejercicios?¿O quieres hacer respuestas para los ejercicios que mas se repiten? En cualquiera de los 2 casos me parece mala idea, ese tipo de preguntas deberían de ser cerradas y no marcarlas como duplicadas. Se pueden reportar para agilizar el sistema y que lleguen a las colas de revisión y que mas gente pueda votar para cerrar.

Comment: A. Cedano sería bueno que clarificaras la pregunta, pues cada cual la está interpretando de una forma diferente: ¿quiered preguntas canónicas o preguntas para "verter" las malas preguntas como duplicadas?

Answer (score 6):

Creo que es una idea muy buena y que es hacia donde debe ir la comunidad: crear preguntas y respuestas muy buenas que acumulen el conocimiento y sean el destino para marcar muchas preguntas como duplicadas.

La clave aquí está en determinar cuáles son las preguntas canónicas necesarias. En Spanish.SE tenemos en Meta una pregunta [*¿Qué temas necesitan una pregunta canónica?*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3079/1674), lo mismo sería interesante hacer lo mismo aquí.

También habrá casos en que no habrá pregunta canónica a la que apuntar: son preguntas muy básicas o de "hazme este ejercicio". Para estos casos es importante seguir lo que comentábamos en [¿Cómo gestionar las preguntas que son ejercicios de clase?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4365/83) hace unos días: pedir más datos, editar para clarificar, no caer en votar negativo masivamente, etc.

Finalmente, como [comentaba JackNavaRow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4365/c%C3%B3mo-gestionar-las-preguntas-que-son-ejercicios-de-clase/4366#comment18089_4365), sería interesante poner algún tipo de "aviso" cuando alguien plantee una pregunta que tenga ciertas palabras del tipo "ejercicio", "clase" o similares. Sería cuestión de crear una pregunta con [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva), [advertencias-en-preguntas](/questions/tagged/advertencias-en-preguntas) y [filtros-de-calidad](/questions/tagged/filtros-de-calidad).

Answer (score 5):

Con respecto a las *"preguntas / respuesta canónicas"*  estoy muy de acuerdo, aunque hay que tener un poco de cuidado, tal vez lo que se considera una respuesta canónica, exija al usuario aplicar una abstracción importante a su problema puntual, que no está en condiciones de hacer, en estos casos puntuales, en mi opinión, es mejor responder la pregunta y en todo caso dejar una referencia a la canónica.

Ahora, con respecto a tu pregunta, lo que entiendo que propones es usar más frecuentemente  este mecanismo para cerrar rápidamente preguntas que no cumplen con los mínimos estándares de la comunidad (las llamaré a partir de ahora de "mala calidad"), pero que terminan recogiendo muchas respuestas. Para esto, tengo algunos reparos y/o comentarios:

- Si la pregunta es de mala calidad, ¿Cómo podremos de todas formas, asumir, que la canónica la vaya a responder?
- Si la pregunta es de mala calidad, me parece, que ese debiera ser el motivo de cierre, previo tratar que el usuario mejore dicha pregunta. Entonces, creo que **el problema es por que no cerramos más rápido estas preguntas** y damos menos chances de que sean respondidas.
- Creo que el esquema de las preguntas canónicas se aplicaría mejor a preguntas claramente formuladas y no a las de mala calidad.
- Me pregunto, si las preguntas de mala calidad terminan, mas temprano o más tarde, cerradas, ¿Que tan grave es el problema que estás recojan respuestas? sin duda puede ser molesto para el que se tomó el trabajo de responder y luego le cierran la pregunta, pero, eventualmente esta situación ¿no tiene su cuota de capacitación? (yo al menos, he aprendido así, como funciona el sitio, mejor o más rápido que leyendo la documentación). Si por supuesto hay una merma  en la calidad general del sitio, pero para esto, ataquemos lo que decía en en el segundo punto.
- En lo personal, me dá lo mismo que estas preguntas sean wiki o de un autor en particular, no veo mal que cualquiera recoja puntos, si ha hecho un pregunta / respuesta bien elaborada, tengo sí, mis dudas, con aquellas que son traducciones mas o menos fieles.

Comment: Buen análisis. Realmente lo que urge es cerrar rápido y que los que contestan a preguntas malas no se vean excesivamente recompensados.

Answer (score 4):

**Edito** la respuesta, porque parece que no entendí bien la primera parte de la pregunta, así que eliminaré esa parte y me centro aquí en lo referente a las *preguntas canónicas*:

Creo que estaría bien crear una etiqueta [pregunta-respuesta-canonica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pregunta-respuesta-canonica) (por ejemplo) para encontrar rápidamente la lista de preguntas que suelen ser enlazadas para marcar como relacionadas o duplicadas. Es engorroso marcar duplicadas cuando cuesta encontrar la respuesta original.

Entiendo que esto sería una meta-etiqueta, que no son aconsejadas, pero creo que en este caso se podría hacer una excepción:

Creo que no encajaría con [los motivos por los que se *prohibieron*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), entre otras cosas porque no las pondría el OP, se añadirían *a posteriori*

No sé si hay etiquetas que sólo puedan poner moderadores o usuarios con cierta reputación/medallas, pero **necesitamos** un índice de preguntas de referencia y el buscador del sitio puede ser frustrante a la hora de mostrar resultados.

Comment: Oh, no entendí la pregunta así. ¿Lo entiendes como que se marcara como duplicada a una pregunta que no sería pregunta sino una indicación de que esa pregunta no vale? En tal caso estoy de acuerdo en que no es la manera. Además, requeriría tener distintas, una para cada etiqueta de gran volumen, pues los que tienen medalla de oro solo pueden cerrar unilateralmente aquellas preguntas que tienen la etiqueta específica.

Comment: En cuanto a preguntas canónicas, creo que añadir una etiqueta específica sería algo así como una meta etiqueta y es algo que no se recomienda. En Spanish.SE tenemos una pregunta [¿Qué respuestas canónicas tenemos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) donde las listamos y luego marcamos así en la pregunta en sí. La idea está tomada de Server Fault: [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986)

Comment: @fedorqui yo también lo entendí como tú, por eso he pedido aclaración a a.cedano sobre su propuesta. En caso de ser como nos dice pablo, yo tampoco estaría de acuerdo

Comment: @fedorqui No se recomiendan (pero no se prohíben, entiendo) las meta-etiquetas, pero precisamente es una etiqueta para la moderación, que es algo *meta*. Creo que en este caso estaría justificada la excepción a la norma

Comment: Viendo cómo lo manejan en Server Fault (por aquello de copiar lo que funciona :D) allí mantienen la publicación de _what are the canonical answers..._ actualizada y "marcan" las preguntas así definidas con una entradilla común (ejemplo: https://serverfault.com/q/384686). Después siempre está bien poner esta información en la wiki de la etiqueta, por si alguien algún día la lee. No me parece que nadie quiera navegar por las preguntas así marcadas, por lo que creo que usar una etiqueta común simplemente ayuda a los que moderan... que ya sabrían encontrarlas en Meta. Opino, vaya.

Comment: Veo más limpio poner una etiqueta que editar la pregunta para poner "Esto es una pregunta canónica", pero si lo veis mejor así, también me vale :D

Comment: Jejeje llevas razón que "ensucia" un poco la pregunta, sí.

Comment: Pablo yo no me refiero a hacer algo tan pobre como: *Esto no lo puedes preguntar bla, bla, bla*. Tampoco tengo claro cómo podría hacerse en caso de que fuese factible. Puse el ejemplo de la pregunta/respuesta sobre NPE porque indica más o menos lo que tengo en mente, pero a un nivel más global quizá.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo los dos primeros párrafos de la pregunta, las preguntas que no se adaptan al sitio se cierran y no tienen nada que ver con duplicadas o buscar preguntas de referencia... ¿Qué me estoy perdiendo?

Comment: Pablo no sé si el planteamiento es confuso en la pregunta. Lo que quiero decir es que ese tipo de preguntas sería más fácil cerrarlas cuando se marcan como duplicadas (por un usuario con medalla de oro) y que podría ser bueno tener una pregunta a la que referirse para dicho cierre. Así se mantendría el sitio más limpio de preguntas con respuestas que no aportan nada, porque entre que la pregunta recibe los votos de cierre necesarios hay muchos casos en los que usuarios inexpertos responden a ella.

Answer (score 0):

Resumen

En otras respuesta ya se mencionaron criticas sobre las idea de la pregunta, en esta respuesta menciono a las wiki de etiqueta como un elemento al que le podríamos sacar mayor provecho para orientar a los nuevos usuarios cuando ya existe una respuesta a su pregunta y en sobre cómo pregunta o no hacerlo con base en ejemplos,

---

En los wiki de etiqueta es válido incluir las FAQ destacados por la comunidad que corresponden a la etiqueta. Podríamos agregar, indicaciones específicas sobre cuales son las preguntas más comunes de la "**marea académica**" para lo cual podríamos tener listadas algunas malas preguntas que hayan tenido una o varias excelentes respuestas acompañadas de acotaciones, como

> no la tomes como ejemplo para preguntar o justificar una pregunta que ha sido cerrada, sin embargo, una o varias de las respuestas incluidas son buenas, considéralas como ejemplo para responder.

A estas preguntas, podríamos hacer un "esfuerzo extra" por agregar respuestas que incluyan **suficientes** anotaciones / referencias para que alguien que recién empieza con los conceptos principales a los que se refiere la pregunta pueda entender la respuesta y adaptarla a su necesidades particulares.

En el wiki de etiqueta además podrían darse indicaciones, si es que estas aún no están, sobre cómo hacer una buena pregunta y que es lo que deberá incluir como mínimo para ser reabierta en caso de que una pregunta haya sido marcada como duplicado.

Notas

**Septiembre eterno** se refiere a tener un flujo constante de nuevos usuarios cometiendo errores de novato. Me gusta más el término **marea académica** porque el flujo de las preguntas de tipo "resuélvanme el ejercicio" no es constante, sino que tiene sus altas y bajas, que coinciden con el inicio de ciclo académico, en esta época del año, de España, y en marzo de Sudamérica, según me parece.

En los sitios en inglés es común referirse al privilegio de los que tienen medalla de oro de cerrar como duplicado como **dupe-hammer**. Me parece que este termino no se ha usado mucho aún por acá.

Comment: *dupe-hammer*... me lo apunto, me ha gustado el término. Había visto *golden hammer*, pero no me gusta porque tiene otro [significado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)