# ¿Cuál sería el mejor uso para la opción de llamar a un moderador en los reportes?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, reportes

Hace mucho se me habilitó la opción de los reporte. En lo poco que llevo en la plataforma he sido bastante activo, y quería saber cuál es el mejor uso que se le puede dar a la opción `reportar`... para poder utilizar la herramienta de la mejor manera.

Comment: En principio, la opción de reportar a un moderador debe ser la última opción, y sólo para casos que no estan contemplados en las otras opciones de reporte. Puedes leer [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2227/una-teor%C3%ADa-de-moderaci%C3%B3n) en la que se explica un poco como se debe moderar en [es.so]. Ahí se especifica _Si ves ve algo en el sistema que es malo, extraño, o excepcional de alguna manera y merece la atención del moderador ♦ por cualquier motivo ... ¡repórtalo!_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Diferencias de cada tipo de [reporte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)**

> [image: popup de reportar]

- **contenido no deseado**. Es spam, pura y llanamente spam, que directa o indirectamente es una publicidad de algún producto.

  Es (generalmente) relativamente sencillo de identificar. Simplemente te aconsejo tener en cuenta que Stack Overflow tiene una política abierta a permitir enlaces a otros sitios, [productos de terceros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) (incluso productos pagos), etc. Si tiene algo que ver con la pregunta, no es spam. Si es una publicidad y la publicación tiene que ser eliminada porque no hay forma de editarla para salvarla, reportala con este motivo.
- **irrespetuoso o abusivo**. No se está respondiendo, sino que se está atacando a algo o a alguien de manera irrespetuosa.

  Generalmente se trata de  un usuario enojado o pasando un mal momento, que decidió usar una publicación para escribir malas palabras o similar, algo que de ninguna manera tiene lugar en el sitio y debe ser eliminado a toda costa, sin lugar a dudas. De nuevo, no se trata de una simple expresión como "*IE es una cagada*" o algo que cualquiera pueda editar para llevarlo a un plano más formal. Es una publicación que está completamente fuera de lugar y no se está respondiendo a una pregunta en lo más mínimo.
- **debería ser cerrada** (sólo en preguntas). Para usuarios con menos de 3000 de reputación. Abre un 2do popup con opciones de cierre. Se emplea en cualquier pregunta que creas que debería ser cerrada. Este es un tema un poco largo de describir en detalle, pero en general es para cuando son poco claras, demasiado amplias, basadas principalmente en opiniones, de algún modo hacen difícil identificar el problema, o está fuera de [los temas tratados en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y tampoco está dentro de [otros temas también tratados por la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/127). Te recomiendo leer [Emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (el privilegio a los 3000 de reputación). Las preguntas que fueron cerradas y aún no fueron eliminadas se encuentran en [esta búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3Ayes%20duplicate%3Ano).
- **un duplicado** (sólo en preguntas) para preguntas cuyas respuestas ya se encuentran en otra publicación. Al seleccionar esta opción, pide el enlace a la pregunta de la cual es duplicado. Por ejemplo, [todas estas preguntas ya fueron marcadas como duplicadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=duplicate%3Ayes).
- **no es una respuesta** (sólo en respuestas). Cuando se publicó algo que no responde a la pregunta. Puede ser un comentario pidiéndole al autor de la pregunta que aclare algo, un comentario diciendo "gracias" o "tengo el mismo problema", algo que el autor de la pregunta debería haber puesto en la pregunta en vez de en una respuesta, una pregunta nueva, etc. Esto NO es para una respuesta incorrecta. Ver [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/127).
- **muy baja calidad** (sólo en publicaciones que no cumplen ciertos filtros). Para contenido que es pura y exclusivamente basura. Contenido que no tiene salvación de ninguna manera posible. Que quede claro, esto NO es para una respuesta incorrecta, por más que se haya equivocado feo (ahí se vota -1 y nada más). Es para cuando lo que se publicó está más allá de todo reconocimiento posible. Una publicación que sea de muy baja calidad no es tan frecuente.
- **se necesita la intervención de un moderador**. Para todo el resto, en el cual aparece un campo de texto para completar con una breve descripción y que un moderador va a evaluar personalmente, tomar la acción correcta, y marcar tu reporte si fue útil o no.

  > [image: input en "se necesita la intervención de un moderador"]

**¿Cuándo usar estos reportes?** Lo más frecuentemente que puedas. Le hace bien al sitio cuando sus miembros toman un rol activo en la moderación. El mejor consejo que te puedo dar es que lo uses sin miedo. En el peor de los casos, el reporte será rechazado. Sin embargo, usándolo de forma responsable, serían pocos los rechazos y no tendría ninguna implicancia en absoluto sobre tu usuario.

La red de sitios de Stack Exchange es [moderado por la propia comunidad (por ti)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2227/una-teor%C3%ADa-de-moderaci%C3%B3n). Este tipo de acciones son las que moderan el contenido de SOes y estás más que invitado a participar activamente en esta tarea.

Desde ya, te recomiendo **revisar el resultado de tus reportes**, para ver si lo hiciste bien, y si fue útil, rechazado, o [en disputa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1944/127). Se puede acceder al estado de tus reportes dentro de [tu perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current):

> [image: dentro del enlace "reportes útiles"]
>   Haciendo click en ese enlace se accede al listado con todos tus reportes y su resolución.

Se aprende probando, evaluando los resultados, buscando si hay algo sobre ese tema específico, y haciendo una pregunta acá en Meta cuando no lo tengas claro. Con un uso responsable, un reporte rechazado no significa nada... Claro que demasiados reportes rechazados podrían bloquearte de realizar más, pero no hay ningún motivo para que te preocupes por eso.

**¿Quién evalúa los reportes?** Para los casos de cierre, duplicados, no es una respuesta o muy baja calidad, un reporte los envía a [las colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review). Eso significa que normalmente son evaluados por otros miembros de la comunidad con la suficiente reputación para revisarlas. Cualquiera de estas podría ser evaluada directamente por un [moderador ♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), pero eso ya es opcional o parte de una segunda instancia.

Los casos de contenido no deseado o irrespetuoso o abusivo, son exclusivamente tratados por un moderador porque implican una sanción sobre un usuario. Sin embargo, si juntan la suficiente cantidad de reportes de diferentes usuarios, se pueden eliminar automáticamente sin necesidad de que un moderador intervenga.

**¿Cuándo reportar como que *se necesita la intervención de un moderador*?** Cuando hay un tema que no puede ser solucionado en un tiempo razonable con las herramientas a tu disposición (comentarios, votos, cierres, otros tipos de reportes, publicaciones en meta, etc.), o cuando no se tiene la suficiente reputación para hacerlo.

Algunos ejemplos:

- Contenido ilegal o sin la atribución requerida.
- Acciones que van más allá de una sola publicación, y que requieren que se evalúen a diferentes publicaciones en conjunto.
- Comportamientos indeseados de usuarios que siguen un patrón que debería ser corregido, probablemente contactándolo directamente.
- Solicitar que una pregunta se convierta en wiki de comunidad (conviene discutirlo en Meta previamente).
- Pedidos de combinaciones (*merge*) (también, ver en Meta).
- Corregir la autoría de una [pregunta huérfana](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3177/127).
- Cualquier acción donde conviene que intervenga un tercero antes de *seguir agregando leña al fuego*.
- Cualquier otro reporte que amerite una pequeña descripción para poder evaluar la acción correctamente.
- Corregir etiquetas de estado en Meta.
- etc.

De nuevo, usalos sin miedo. Le hacen bien a la comunidad y están para ser usados y mejorar así al sitio. Muchas veces un moderador va a preferir que un reporte, que de otra manera sería difícil de evaluar, vaya con una descripción aclarando a qué te estás refiriendo. Vas a poder ver el resultado en tu perfil una vez que se haya evaluado y ver si estuvo bien que lo hayas reportado así. Si un moderador necesitara hacerte alguna aclaración, puede ponerlo como comentario en la resolución del reporte (o contactarte en un chat, según el caso).

Comment: Si saben de algún enlace más que ayude, agreguen sin miedo en esta respuesta

Comment: ¡¡¡Fantástica respuesta!!!